# Webrequest not returning expected result

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to retrieve data from our time management service to create a desktop client that warns you when you're close to your maximum work time. To achieve this I want to use HttpWebRequests.

This is what I've got by now (qnd):

```
class Program {
        private static readonly string mainurl = "[...]/autontlogin.jsp";
        private static readonly string mojouUri = "[...]/mojoudata.jsp";
static void Main(string[] args) {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(mainurl);
            CookieContainer jar = new CookieContainer();
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.CookieContainer = jar;
            request.UserAgent =
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0; Firefox 45.7.0 - 11712-1500630279-1.26";
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                } catch (WebException e) {
                    Console.WriteLine(GetText(e.Response.GetResponseStream()));
                }
            }
            HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(mojouUri);
            request2.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            request2.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            request2.Method = "GET";
            request2.MediaType = "HTTP/1.1";
            request2.ContentType = "text/html";
            request2.CookieContainer = jar;
            request2.UserAgent =
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0; Firefox 45.7.0 - 11712-1500630279-1.26";
            var response2 = request2.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(GetText(response2?.GetResponseStream()));

        }

        static string GetText(Stream s) {
            var sr = new StreamReader(s);
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I can not share the exact links with you but this shouldn't matter (those servers are located in our intranet).

As far as I understand I have to call the autontlogin.jsp to get required Cookies (JSessionid) - but unfortunately I receive an internal Server Error (500).

When calling the same address with a firefox plugin (HttpRequester) (cleared cookies & cache) it works as expected. Am I missing something when building the request?

**Edit 1**

This is what happens when navigating to the page with a cleared cache and cookies:

[image: Overview]

Successfull Header:

[image: Successfull Header]

The first request object contains two items in the Header - Content-Type and User-Agent.

The 500 Error Response sais:

```
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit 2**

This is the request done by the firefox addon HttpRequester:

```
GET [...]/autontlogin.jsp

 -- response --
200 200
Content-Length:  1918
Content-Type:  text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Server:  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie:  JSESSIONID=D2150640BEB566B6DACD7AD58B704A93;path=/WebClient/;Secure;HttpOnly userlocale=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5;Max-Age=259200
Persistent-Auth:  true
Date:  Thu, 02 Mar 2017 08:05:56 GMT
```

Comment: Well at least attach raw request (with headers etc) from HttpRequester so we can compare. Also internal server error will usually be reflected somewhere in the logs of your management service.

Comment: If there's an internal server error, you should look at the server logs to see what's going on.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't have access to the servers log files.

Comment: I suggest you request access then - you've said it's an internal service, so it shouldn't be a problem. You don't necessarily need full access, of course: if you say "I made a request at time X, there should be an error logged" that's all you need. No PII or anything...